# inactive contact google contacts api

Tags: google-contacts-api

Good day. I apologize in advance - my English is terrible. (This is translator).
I have a problem while working with Google Contacts API.

I try to create a contact:

```
    <atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
<atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
  term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
<gd:name>
   <gd:givenName>Sergey</gd:givenName>
   <gd:familyName>Serov</gd:familyName>
   <gd:fullName>Sergey Serov</gd:fullName>
</gd:name>
<atom:content type="text">Notes</atom:content>
<gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work"
  primary="true">
  +79130968888
</gd:phoneNumber>
</atom:entry>
```

Contact was successfully created. But I can not use it.
Contact is not active. It does not synchronize with the phone.
I do not see it in my contact list (Web Interface)
I find it can only be through the "search".
If I change via the web interface 1 letter and save - contact becomes active.

Something wrong with my query?

Thanks

Comment: Did you receive any kind of error message?

Answer (score 0):

Everything works well. 
Add this line to the query :

```
<gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted="false" href="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/MyMail@gmail.com/base/6" />
```